# Visual studio with TFS: How to avoid deployment mistakes?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I keep making mistakes when deploying SSRS, SSIS & SSAS solutions from VS to different environments. For example deploying a SSIS package change to Dev, but the connection strings are pointing at Production. I fix the mistake update the connections, and check back in to TFS. The next time I look the changes haven't stuck. So everytime I move between branches and environments I have to double and triple check every connection, and rebuild every solution to ensure I don't break something.

Surely it shouldn't be this hard? Is there a better way to do this?

Does anyone have a solution for verifying that package connections in TFS are set per environment? Dev=Dev, test=test, Live=Live etc. Can this be queried somehow?

Is there a better option that storing the connection strings within TFS?

Currently on TFS 2018 Version 16.122.27102.1 (Feb 2018)

Comment: For SSRS, we use the same name for data sources to PROD, DEV and UAT report servers. The server it's deployed to uses the data source on that server which is pointed to the correct environment. Just make sure `Overwrite Datasources/Datasets` is *False*. I don't have any good solutions for SSIS - we are going to start using the package deployment for connections strings (et al) but haven't yet.

Comment: @HannoverFist Thanks for replying. Yes we do the same with SSRS, I guess it's SSIS that is my biggest issue. Now that we have configurations setup I seldom deploy to the wrong report server

Comment: Use the built-in build and deployment automation features to automate your build and deployment so that you have a repeatable process that eliminates the possibilities for mistakes.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for suggestion. Ill need to look into it more.